# vertical-align property not working in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I want to display a calculation with exponents (and more). To set the elements in line i use flexbox. Within the flexbox element i want to make use of the `vertical-align` CSS property. But the `vertical-align` property doesn't work.

I tested it with different approaches and in the end one solution worked. But then the `justify-content` property is not working anymore. in my attempt i used for the property: `flex` the webkit version: `-webkit-box.`

Here is the snipped in a fiddle if you want to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/oe3hxfma/

```css
.calculation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.exponent {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: super;
}

.calculationTwo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculation">
  3
  <div class="exponent">
    2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="calculationTwo">
  3
  <div class="exponent">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i make use of the vertical-align when the parent elmenet is displayed as flexbox.

Comment: isn't it `align-self` and `align-items` you need? IIRC `vertical-align` only works on inline or inline-block display properties. The aforementioned properties work on any display: flex; parent/children.

Comment: `display: -webkit-box;` is obsolete and no longer used.

Comment: is there a way to use `align-self` and `align-items` to change the `baseline` of one element?

Comment: @Paulie_D the angular build extents code for better browser-support. And -webkit-box does he add by `display:flex`.

Answer (score 3):

The `vertical-align` property works only with inline-level and table-cell elements ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)).

Because the `exponent` element is a child of a flex container, it is automatically *blockified* ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)). This means it computes to a block-level element and `vertical-align` is ignored.

It doesn't matter how you define the `display` value for the flex item (e.g., in your code you have the flex item set to `display: inline`). In a [flex formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), the `display` value of flex items is controlled by the flex algorithm.

The key to using `vertical-align` is to remove it from a flex formatting context. Create an element that is a child of the flex item. Now the exponent value is outside the scope of flex layout, and you can set it to `display: inline`.

Also, because the text is aligned to the top of the container, there is no space for `vertical-align: super` to work. So align the text to the center or bottom of the container.

Add `align-items: flex-end` or `center` (depending on how much superscripting you want).

```css
.calculation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

span {
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculation">
  3
  <div class="exponent">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One option, give the parent a larger height and align the exposnent individually - https://jsfiddle.net/syn478hv/

Comment: okay thanks for the explanation so i have to wrap it in an extra `div`? Not the best solution just to show one element.

Comment: @Paulie_D thats pretty interesting. i dont know you have to set the height to align the items with `align-self`.

Comment: @LukasSedelmaier, if you want to use `vertical-align` in a flex container, then yes. Wrapping the exponent value in a nested container, putting it outside the scope of flex layout, is the way to go.

Comment: Otherwise, follow the suggestion of @Paulie_D. Add a height to the container (to create free space) and use flex keyword alignment properties.

Comment: One final suggestion: If the only reason you're using flex is to horizontally center the content, then you don't really need flex. Just use `text-align: center`. https://jsfiddle.net/us1hLat7/

Answer (score 1):

You should use "align-items" property to align items in vertical position:

```
.container {
  align-items: stretch | flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline;
}
stretch: fit in the container,
flex-start: align item vertically upward,
flex-end: align items vertically downward,
center: align items to vertically center,
baseline: items are aligned such as their baselines align
```

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion, why don't you try to use `sup` HTML Tag for exponential?

```
<div>
3 <sup>2</sup>
</div>
```

and for `vertical alignment`, `display:flex` use `align-items` like in above answers.

```css
div
{
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    3 <sup>2</sup>
    </div>
```

```css
.calculation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

span {
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculation">
  3
  <div class="exponent">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try give the content some padding and use the align-items: stretch feature of flex.

Here is a very useful guide to flex! It's awesome to keep it in your back-pocket as a front end developer!

[Flexbox Guide!](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)